# Correct use of  "me too" and "I too"

Tags: word-choice

I would like to say to a boy that he is strange and, fortunately, I am strange too, without repeating.

How do I write it with "me too" or "I too"?

Comment: Why are you calling someone strange? That's not going to go over well.

Comment: It is fun to be strange and not like other))

Comment: If you say it in English, people might take it as an insult, even if you don't mean it that way. Maybe you might use "unique"?

Comment: hmm.... okay.     
let it be "unique". Thanks
So, how to write it correctly?

Comment: hey hey hey. Can somebody help me? How to call my friends I'll decide myself.

Comment: @Theta30 And usage has connotations.

Comment: See also [Is it correct to use “me too” and “I too”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4576/is-it-correct-to-use-me-too-and-i-too)

Answer (score 6):

- never say "I too". That just doesn't work in English.
- You can respond to a statement by saying "me too":

> A: "I am strange"
>
> B: "Me too!" (B would never say "I too").

- If you are writing a statement more formally, you'd want to say:

> "You are strange and so am I"

or

> "You are strange. I am too."

Comment: so, if i write "You are strange and,fortunately, so am I", it will be correct. Won't it?

Comment: @Anna: Yes, that is grammatically correct. You can substitute any adjective in for 'strange'.

Answer (score 3):

The most common response would be:

> Me too.

This is not a sentence but an interjection, and so the objective form would be used, rather than "I too".

If you put it in a sentence you would use the nominative case:

> I am too.

So the unusual form "me too" comes about because it isn't a sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat formally, one could say

> Like you, I too am strange.
>
> You are strange, and I too am strange.

More commonly in conversation, one would say something like

> You're strange— just like me.
>
> You're strange, like I am.
>
> You're strange. That makes two of us.
>
> You're strange, but so am I.

By the way, little self-deprecation can soften the words and ensure it's received as a friendly comment:

> You're strange, but not as strange as I am.

Answer (score 2):

"I" is used for a subject, and "me" for an object. In this case, if you were writing it out, you would say "You are strange, and I too am strange" because "I" is the subject of the sentence. If you don't want to repeat the word "strange", you could say, "You are strange, and I am too." It wouldn't be grammatically correct to just say "... and I too" because that would make what is supposed to be an independent clause with no verb.

As I say, for an object you would use "me". Like, "People like you, and they like me too." If you want to leave out the "like" you have to combine it into a single clause, e.g. "People like you and me". I guess you could say, "People like you and me too." You'd say it with a pause after "you" so maybe it would be appropriate to include a comma there, though English teachers would probably mark that wrong as it has no grammatical justification.

As Mitch notes, people sometimes say "Me too" as shorthand for repeating a lot of words. Like if A says "I am strange", a response in a complete sentence would be "I am strange too". But people often abbreviate this to "Me too". I suppose you could say that to be grammatically consistent we should say "I too" because the "self" being referred to is the subject. But almost no one actually says that. Neither "Me too" nor "I too" is a copmlete sentence anyway, so maybe it's pointless to debate its grammatical correctness.

Answer (score 0):

If both sentences are complete with a sentence and a verb, and joined by a conjunction, then you can use "I" with "too".

"You are strange, and I am too."
"I think you are strange, fortunately, I am also strange."

You may want to avoid "too" with "fortunately", because it will cause the sentence to be choppy from all the commas. 
"I think you are strange, fortunately, I, too, am strange."

Comment: And if I write "You are strange and,fortunately,I am too", will it be correctly?

Comment: You would want a comma after "strange" in that situation.