# "Me too" or "I as well"

Tags: grammaticality, expression-choice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it correct to use “me too” and “I too”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4576/is-it-correct-to-use-me-too-and-i-too)

Which one is correct to use *Me too* or *I as well*?

For example - Suppose my friend says I want to go there and I want to say, Me too/I as well.

Or Is there any batter expression for such situations?

Comment: Use either, "Me too", or "I do too."  A native speaker would not say, "I as well."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In formal writing, the pronoun should technically be the same case as the noun or pronoun in the original sentence. For example, if someone says, "He gave a book to me", you might say, "Me, too". But if someone says, "I gave him a book", the technically correct statement would be, "I, too" or "I, as well" or "So did I".

In speech and informal writing, people almost always use "Me, too." And frankly, this point is so pedantic that in any context if you wrote "Me, too" instead of "I, too" I think few would question it.

Answer (score 3):

As Jim mentioned in his comment, "*Me too*" would be a very common response in your situation.

Although "*too*" and "*as well*" are almost perfectly synonymous, in short responses, "*too*" is preferred.

This is because it's not common to use "*as well*" **without a verb**.

> Me/ I as well.

But you could say (**with a verb**):

> I *want to go there* as well.

Or (**with the helping verb**):

> I *do* as well.